# Current branch test is up to date

Tags: git, github

right so here follows the list of an activity i have been trying to work on:

1. Go to the GitHub website to access the practice project.
2. Fork the repository to your GitHub account.
3. Clone the repository with Git on your computer.
4. Use `git log` to look at the file structure and commits.  Note how, many commits, trees, and blobs there are.  Take a screenshot.
5. Create a new branch called "test," and checkout.
6. Use  `git log`  to look at your new branch.
7. Create a new file called  test.txt.
8. Write “GitHub is awesome!” in your file, and save it using a text editor.
9. Add and commit your new file to your branch. Take a screenshot.
10. Run a  `git fetch`  to see if any new files are on the main repo. Take a screenshot.
11. Use  `git merge`  to merge your branch to the master branch on your local repo.
    **Get on the master branch as your working directory.** this item  is the one giving me trouble

I've used `git checkout test` and then when I try to `git rebase master` I get this message:

> Current branch test is up to date.

not sure what to do

any ideas?

Comment: If I've got you correctly, you should switch to `master` branch of you local repo, to see your newly adde file there?
`git checkout master`.
What are you expecting to see at your `test` branch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make at least one commit in order for your `test` branch, which started from `master`, to have anything to rebase to.

If that test branch has commits not present on `master`, then the rebase won't tell you that everything is up-to-date.